# proc summary with statistic "multiply"

Tags: sas, summary

Is it possible to make a new statistic with proc summary that multiplies every value in each column, for example instead of just mean? SAS is so rigid it makes me crazy.

```
data test;                                                
    input b c ;                                 
    datalines;                                                
    50 11                                       
    35 12                                        
    75 13                                       
    ;
```

Desired output would be 50*35*75, and 11*12*13, and _FREQ (as is normal output in proc summary)

Comment: Why do you need to use PROC means? Is a data step prior or entirely acceptable?

Comment: Yes, data step is acceptable instead of *proc summary*. I just thought one should be able to choose one's own statistic

Comment: No, proc means does a specific set of statistics, the doc has the list http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/69850/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0v0y1on1hbxukn0zqgsp5ky8hc0.htm

Comment: If you want matrix type functionality look at PROC IML.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll look into matrix functionality, although your answer solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an uncommon aggregate so you essentially need to roll your own. Since a data step loops this is easily accomplished using a RETAIN to keep value from row to row and outputting result at the last record.

```
 Data want;
   Set have end=eof;
   Retain prod_b prod_c;
   prod_b = prod_b * b;
   prod_c = prod_c * c;
   Freq= _n_;
 If eof then OUTPUT; 
  Keep prod: freq;
 Run;
```